# Profile is not loaded for all the users

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I recently got arm-linux-gcc toolchain up and running for my Ubuntu OS. I have configure the path variable for the toolchain in /etc/profile file. I am able to access the toolchain only when I am logged in as root and that too, I have to do

```
source /etc/profile
```

in every session. Why does this happen? why am I not able to access the toolchain from normal login.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Probably you're not running a login-shell.

It depends a bit on the shell you're using. I use Bash, but maybe you use BusyBox?

From the bash manual:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive
>   login shell, or as a non-interactive
>   shell with the --login option, it
>   first reads and  executes  commands
>   from  the  file /etc/profile, if that
>   file exists.  After reading that file,
>   it looks for ~/.bash_profile,
>   ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that
>          order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
>   exists and is readable.

What I usually do to resolve this issue, is put:

```
source /etc/profile
```

as first line in my ~/.bashrc.

This works because ~/.bashrc is also executed for non-login shells.

To see which files are executed, you might want to put diagnostic messages in them. If I can't remember which files are executed at what type I login, I put:

```
echo /etc/profile/
```

as first line in my /etc/profile, the same for /etc/bash/bashrc, ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile and so on.

For more info, consult the "INVOCATION" part of the bash-manual.